# Graph - How to change the color of the Y line from a certain day?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have one question.
How Can I change the color of the Y line from a certain day?
[image]

For example I want to change the color to red the price from the 100th day:
[image]

I have the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cryptocurrency.prices)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit="s")
df.set_index("time", inplace=False)
df["close"].plot(figsize=(12, 8), title=cryptocurrency.name, label="Price")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

So suppose that I have a data frame as follows, which is called df:

```
    median_house_value
1             176500.0
2             270500.0
3             330000.0
4              81700.0
5              67000.0
..                 ...
95             96000.0
96             90600.0
97            121900.0
98            209400.0
99            200000.0
```

And with the following code, we have reached the plot you see:

```
df['median_house_value'].plot(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

And I separate the desired part of the dataframe in this way:

```
df1 = df[50:100]
```

df1:

```
    median_house_value
51             47500.0
52            156500.0
53            187500.0
54            191800.0
..                 ...
98            209400.0
99            200000.0
```

And we have the new plot as follows:

```
df["median_house_value"].plot(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(df1["median_house_value"], 'r')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]